# Insert statement and create table oracle

Tags: oracle

My tables are been created, but when I am trying to put the insert statements it's giving me an error saying parent not found.

This is my create table:

```
Create table patient (    
    Patient_ID Number(9) primary key,
    First_name varchar2(15),
    Last_name varchar2(10),
    Contact number(10),
    City varchar2(20),
    Doctor_ID Number(9) references Doctor(Doctor_ID)    
);
```

This is the insert statement:

```
insert into patient (Patient_ID, First_name, Last_name, Contact, City, Doctor_ID) values ('21345', 'John', 'Smith', '1111111111', 'NY', '30111');
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the exact error message. I think the exact message will give you the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
insert into patient (Patient_ID, First_name, Last_name, Contact, City, Doctor_ID) values (21345, 'John', 'Smith', 1111111111, 'NY', 30111);
```

Don't use quotes for numbers.

Comment: Is your Doctor table present and contains data?

Comment: Yes, the Doctor table works fine and when I do select * from Doctor it shows data.

Comment: please post your doctor table as well

Comment: Create table Doctor (
Doctor_ID Number(9) primary key,
First_name varchar2(15),
Last_name varchar2(10),
Speciality varchar2(15));

Comment: The only thing that will create the error message in your question is if docter_id 30111 is not in the doctor table.